# PHP возвращает знаки вопроса (???) вместо русских символов

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Когда выполняю код, получаю на выходе знаки ???????????????????????, вместо данных, которые хранятся в MySQL

В корень с файлом РНР добавил файл .htaccess с текстом "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8"
У всех переменных кодировка UTF8_general_ci
В редакторе показывает кодировку UTF-8
Хелпаните по-братски)
Вообще новичок в этой теме, кода мало, может тут все на поверхности)

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","u0584147_bodya","bodya123","u0584147_med-list") or die ("Error");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM Tester");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) echo "<h1>".$row['name']."</h1><p>".$row['manufacturer']."<br>".$row['description']."</p><br>";
```

Comment: [SET NAMES utf8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=set+names+%5Bmysql%5D) ?

Comment: Так же, есть вероятность, что ваши php файлы не в кодировке UTF8

Comment: Заголовок покажите в .php : DOCTYPE, HTML , META , TITLE , ...